# Multi Language and Ember Handlebar

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, multilingual

I am wondering what is the best way to realize a multi language support for a web app with handlebars and EmberJs in the back. There is no native multi language support in handlebars.

I found a handlebars helper https://gist.github.com/tracend/3261055 The code looks good and pretty simple, but I didn't test it yet.

Do you know another plugins/helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this one which is specific for Ember:
https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n

It adds a 't' handlebars helper :

```
{{t main.offers countBinding="offers.length"}}
```

It supports plurals (via CDLR.js) and is not limited to handlebars thanks to `Em.I18n.TranslateableProperties` mixin, which allows property translation via a convention on any Ember Object.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to write a helper, so you will find none or many handlebars implementations.

I'm using https://github.com/jquery/globalize for my projects. The implementation is a peace of cake.

Globalize is maintained by JQuery, supports everything you need and has an active community.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will keep it in mind for the next non Ember project.